# Windows Phone check if the phone is Jailbroken or rooted?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way in windows phone 8 or higher to detect if the mobile is jail-broken or rooted, pragmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is any official way of doing it as Microsoft does not support Jailbreaking and rooting.

The only thing I am aware of is the developer unlock but that too you cannot check programatically.

Comment: There are some phones that were rooted ... sort of. On the ATIV S for example one could change some hidden os settings because Samsung had a security flaw in one of their apps. But as you said there is no way of checking this by a code fragment at the moment.